# vim windows 10 set packpath option for native package manager

Tags: vim, gvim

[1] I created a new package directory using the 'packpath' option in my vimrc:

```
:set packpath+=$HOME/vimlocal/pack
```

[2] I run the command :set packpath? and the directory is listed in the output:

```
packpath=

~/vimfiles,
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81,
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,
~/vimfiles/after,
~/vimlocal/pack
```

But none of the plugins (colorschemes) in the directory work. The directory structure is:

```
~/vimlocal/pack/colors/start/color1
~/vimlocal/pack/colors/start/color2
~/vimlocal/pack/colors/start/color3
```

[3] I run the command:

```
:set rtp?
```

but the directory is not listed in the output.

```
runtimepath=

~/vimlocal,
~/vimfiles,
~\vimfiles\bundle\alduin-master,
~\vimfiles\bundle\color-plugins,
~\vimfiles\bundle\ctrlp.vim,
~\vimfiles\bundle\dbext.vim,
~\vimfiles\bundle\goyo.vim,
~\vimfiles\bundle\hexHighlight.vim-master,
~\vimfiles\bundle\limelight.vim,
~\vimfiles\bundle\manpageview,
~\vimfiles\bundle\markdown-preview.nvim-master,
~\vimfiles\bundle\supertab,
~\vimfiles\bundle\tabular,
~\vimfiles\bundle\ultisnips,
~\vimfiles\bundle\utl.vim,
~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-colorschemes,
~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-HiLinkTrace,
~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-markdown-master,
~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-zenroom2,
~\vimfiles\bundle\vimoutliner,
~\vimfiles\bundle\vimtweak-master,
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81,
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\pack\dist\opt\matchit,
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,
~\vimfiles\bundle\vim-markdown-master\after,
~\vimfiles\bundle\ultisnips\after,
~\vimfiles\bundle\tabular\after,
~/vimfiles/after
```

NB: the path '~\vimfiles\bundle....' is set by Pathogen. I'm trying to
migrate all my plugins from there to the new packpath directory.

[4] When I move the colorscheme files to the pack file in

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\pack'
```

(with their same directory structure) they work fine (and appear in output of the runtimepath command).

My question is why are they not working in the directory I set in vimrc with the packpath option?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 4):

You should not include the `pack` component in your `'packpath'` setting, since Vim will add that for you.

What you want is simply:

```
:set packpath+=$HOME/vimlocal
```

Or, better yet, just use the existing `~/vimfiles` and store your plug-ins under `~/vimfiles/pack/colors/start/color1` and so on. If you do that, you don't need to touch `'packpath'` at all.

You can take a look at the documentation on [packages](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#packages), which says:

> When Vim starts up, after processing your `.vimrc`, it scans all directories in `'packpath'` for plugins under the **`pack/*/start`** directory.  First all those directories are added to `'runtimepath'`.  Then all the plugins are loaded.

Emphasis mine. You can see that `pack` is a path component added by Vim, so you shouldn't have it in paths listed in `'packpath'`. In fact, as you can observe, the ones included by Vim already don't include `pack` at all, and yet a `pack` directory right underneath those will work for packages, as you already noticed yourself.